# Writing a c# or c++ application which can detect if browser is going to download a file

Tags: events, browser, download

I am going to write an application which runs in the background on windows platform. If user is working on any browser (IE, Firefox, Chrome, etc) and any of the user action results in downloading activity, the background program should take control. The background program pop-ups a window asking user, if they want to download. If user proceeds with OK, then background program sends signal to browser to stop its download process and the background program will do download. If user rejects download by the background program, then default download of browser can go on.

For this please suggest if any working model is there in c#/VB.NET/C++ or how to achieve this activity.

Will very much appreciate your kind help.

Thanking you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you understand the whole notion of downloading. Any resource you get from the Internet is downloaded. Hence, anything would trigger your application. You can, however, try to "parse" URL to see the extension but this does not have to mean nothing, since you can give any file an arbitrary extension (well not exactly arbitrary, but you know.. ). Another option is detecting FTP downloads ( i assume this might be of more interest ). This way you'd "only" have to check for a specific protocol. The reason i quoted only in the last sentence is that none of these tasks is a simple one. 
You basically want to write a Proxy, or use an existing one. 
You might wanna take a look at [WinPcap](http://www.winpcap.org/)

Finally, none of this options really give you the infromation whether user is *going to* download a file. But if you write a proxy, you could stop the endpoint application of obtaining that file once you download it.